# Why full screen control does not work with Inline tinymce editor?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am working with inline Tinymce editor and i want to use 'fullscreen' control. But , it is not working with inline editor. How to achieve 'fullscreen' feature in Inline mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `fullscreen` plugin does not work with the Inline or Inlite modes.  From looking at the code it decorates an iFrame and that only makes sense in the context of the classic mode of instantiating TinyMCE.

Comment: It's a real shame this is not documented in the official documentation at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/fullscreen/ – I just wasted some time thinking it was a bug in my own code.